# Redirecionar para uma URL à partir do navegador do usuário

Tags: php

Como deveria ser feita o redirecionamento para uma determinada URL a partir do navegador que o usuário esteja utilizando?

Tenho um problema de SSL que ocorre apenas no Firefox, daí gostaria de fazer o seguinte: ao acessar o site `https://`, detectar o navegador do usuário e se for o Firefox redirecionar para o site `http://`.

Comment: Em princípio, não deveria ser feito (a não ser que você tenha um motivo muito especial para isso, é claro). Seria legal acrescentar na pergunta os detalhes relevantes e qual é o problema que está tentando resolver, para ficar claro que não é um **[problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/)** e garantir que as respostas dêem o resultado que você espera. Da forma que está a pergunta, as respostas podem dar mais problemas do que solução.

Comment: Bom, basicamente seria pelo user-agent, mas é facilmente manipulável pelo usuário, você não terá garantias de que um usuário está usando de fato tal navegador. O que você quer pode ser feito pelo PHP ou pelo HTACCESS, mas avalie se vale a pena de fato.

Comment: Você chegou a pesquisar sobre o problema do Firefox com SSL? Tipo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl+firefox

Comment: Agora a questão ficou mais interessante ainda, pois como é que você vai redirecionar pra evitar o erro? A negociação do SSL acontece antes do seu PHP ou mesmo .htaccess ser chamado, então o erro vai acontecer de qualquer jeito. A sequência é mais ou menos assim: Quando você digita `https://exemplo.com` o Browser pega o FQDN `exemplo.com` e faz uma busca de IP por DNS. Isto feito, por ser um protocolo `https://`, conecta por IP na porta 443. Daí acontece a negociação do SSL, (e o seu erro). Depois disso tudo é que é feita a requisição `GET /`, que dá o caminho, e o header HOST, quando o caso.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Ok.

Comment: @brasofilo sim já tinha pesquisado aqui no stackoverflow à respeito, agradeço pela sugestão.

Comment: @Bacco o que ocorre é que no site não está utilizando o redirecionamento por php ou .htaccess para o https:// se eu acessar o site via https:// ele funciona, assim como também vai funcionar acessando via http://